# "enter key" to click a button is refreshing page a split second after running corresponding script

Tags: javascript, html

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Morse Code Translator</title>

    </head>
<body>
    <h3>English to Morse Code Translator</h3>
    <hr />
    <form name = "morseCodeTranslator">

       <!--This is where it should wait for the enter key-->



        Enter your word or phrase: <input type = "text" name = "inputs" value="" id = "yourWord" onkeydown = "if (event.keyCode == 13) document.getElementById('btnSearch').click()"   size = "5">
        <input class = "button" type = "button" value="Translate!" onclick="trans()" id = "btnSearch">
    </form>
    <h6>You can also press the enter key to translate.</h6>
    <hr />
    <script>
    function trans(){//function called by the button
        //get the input
        var yourWord = document.getElementById("yourWord").value;
        //the alphabet
        var alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ";
        //Get everything lowercase
        yourWord = yourWord.toLowerCase().replace(/[^a-z]/g, "");
        //declare the morse code array
        var morseCode = [".-", "-...", "-.-.", "-..", ".", "..-.", "--.", "....", "..", ".---", "-.-",     ".-..", "--", "-.", "---", ".--.", "--.-", ".-.", "...", "-", "..-", "...-", ".--", "-..-", "-.--", "--.."];
        //variables to help out in the loop
        var i;
        var c;
        var x;
        //the first loop for each letter of the input
        for(i = 0; i < yourWord.length; i++){
            c = yourWord.charAt(i);
            for(x = 0; x < 27; x++){ //the next loop for each letter of the alphabet
                if(c == alphabet.charAt(x)){  //match?
                    var d = document.createElement("div");  // Creates a new <div> node
                    d.textContent = morseCode[x] + " | ";         // Sets the text content
                    document.body.appendChild(d);
                }
            }
        } 
    }
    </script>
```

Developer: Desmond Ouckama

This is supposed to be a morse code translator, as you can tell. When you actually click the button, the script runs perfectly, but when I hit enter, it displays the right translation for a split second, and than refreshes the page. I'm not really sure what is going on.

Comment: It's because you are submitting the form. You can either capture the onsubmit event and preventDefault or jsut remove the form tag as it is really only required if you want to submit the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you hit enter, you are submitting the form. All you have to do is prevent the form from submitting:

```
document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit',function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Wow. Thank you. That was easy.

Answer (score 0):

When you enter, you simlate the button click. Any button inside a form has the default behaviour set as 'submit'. you can change that by adding `type=button` to your button's attributes

```
<button class = "button" type="button" onclick="trans()" id = "btnSearch">Translate!</button>
```

Comment: He's using an `input` not a `button`

Comment: he could swap the input for a button like the code I put up